# Password.match isn't working with special characters

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I want to use this regex to check the strength of my password.
But it doesn't really work with this line of code, which I found on an other site. The / causes some problems. How do I have to write it for this list.
I need this list of characters in my regex:()[]{}?!$%&/=*+~,.;:<>-_

```
if (password.match(/([(,),[,],{,},?,!,$,%,&,/,=,*,+,~,])/))
```

Comment: if I remember correctly you don't need commas, just [()\[\]?.....] should be fine

Comment: @Steve ok, will try it like that

Comment: @Steve The slash still causes the problem because it closes the slash from the regex.

Comment: for some reason the back slash did not show up in my comment.. but for any special character you just escape them with back slash and it should work fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Escape. Escape using backslash (`\`).

```
/([()[\]{}?!$%&\/=*+~])/
      ^^       ^^ escaped literals
```

Note that `]` also needed to be escaped.